# In Entity Framework code first, to map a navigation property do I also need to map the foreign key column

Tags: entity-framework-6

Say I have a Trade object which has a foreign key to a Counterparty object. I want to have a navigation property of type Counterparty in my Trade object- do I also need to have the foreign key column (CounterpartyId) in my Trade object? My experimentation seems to indicate that I do. I tried adding [ForeignKey("CounterpartyId"] on the navigation but it doesn't work without also having the CounterpartyId column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the explicit FK property is not mandatory. Just if you skip it, by convention EF assumes `"Counterparty_Id"` *shadow property* and column name in the corresponding database table.

In this case there is no way to configure the shadow property/column name with data annotations, so if you want to do that you'll need fluent configuration with `MapKey` (as opposed to `HasForeignKey` when you do have an explicit property):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Trade>()
    .HasRequired(e => e.Counterparty) // or HasOptional if you want nullable column
    .WithMany() // or WithMany(e => e.Trades) if you have inverse collection navigation property
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("CounterpartyId"));
```

Note that the fluent configuration must reflect **exactly** your model navigation / FK properties. For instance, you later on you decide to add `ConterpartyId` property to your `Trade` object, you should replace the `Map` with

```
.HasForegnKey(e => e.CounterpartyId)
```

Comment: So attribute configuration can only map a subset of what can be mapped in fluent API right? That's a bit of shame, the fluent API is a little verbose. Is it possible to mix attribute mapping with the fluent configuration?

Comment: Correct. And yeah, fluent API is little verbose, but IMO much clear. With attributes (especially for relationships) you never know what exactly are you doing - for instance `ForegnKey` could be applied on navigation property or FK property. And the string depends on where do you apply it. Not speaking about composite PK / FK with attributes which are totally counterintuitive.

Comment: Thanks very much for this, have up-voted your answer. I have posted another question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45007072/object-added-through-collection-navigation-property-not-saved-when-parent-is-det you wouldn't happen to know the answer to that one would you?